# 'router-outlet' is not a known element in angular 6

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I get the following error on a fresh install of angular6 using the angular-cli.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

I followed this guide: https://medium.com/@meemo_86/good-article-beeman-490eaf1399a

And then I followed up on the comment on that article which says to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instead of `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

I do those corrections, then I read up on https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5, and do what is stated there.

So now I have a `AppRoutingModule`, I import that module in app.module.ts, where I also const the routes and added `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` to imports.

But I cannot get this error to go away. What am I doing wrong? When I add `<router-outler></router-outlet>` in my `layout.component.htm`, the app breaks.
I have also searched this topic here and tried several changes but nothing seems to work.

Full source code is here:

https://github.com/ekstremedia/angular6

Comment: In `app.module.ts` file `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` and add `RouterModule.forRoot(your_routes)` to imports.

Comment: AppRoutingModule doesn't do anything. You already import RoutingModule in your AppModule. Actually You import it twice. Try to remove AppRoutingModule from your AppModule and make a fresh compile (ng serve)

Comment: @hrdkisback That is what I have done here: https://github.com/ekstremedia/angular6/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: You didn't import RouterModule in UIModule

Comment: @SplitterAlex that seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I see you are missing **`RouterModule`** inside the imports of UIModule

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  exports: [LayoutComponent]
})
export class UiModule { }
```

Comment: That is correct, and is a working solution. I mark this as correct answer even though SplitterAlex commented it first, but I cannot mark his answer as correct. Thank you anyway Sajeetharan.

Comment: oh sorry i was checking your code that time :) glad SplitterAlex helped :)

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because you are using the router-outlet component in the UIModule and didn't import the RouterModule inside UIModule.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem too. And I already imported the RouterModule inside UIModule, still doesn't work. But after I restart the app, it worked, no more errors.

So, what you should do is:
1. Import the RouterModule inside UIModule;
2. Restart your app

Comment: Worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder `app.module.ts` what i did was I imported the following

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

also don't forget to add it in the `@NgModule`